# How do write that RewriteRule keeping the parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect certain requests to my site to another site, keeping the paramater.

This is the request URL: http://www.example.com/**12345678**
This is where it should go to: http://affiliate.whatever.de/go.cgi?pid=xx&wmid=xxx&cpid=x&prid=xx&target=Suche_Deeplink_Expose&attr1=**12345678**

The bold parameter should be passed over to the new URL. I know I have to use QSA but did not manage to create the rewrite so far.

How can I write that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you would want to '_GET' the url query,

The enter it in a part of the variable into the redirect string.

I dont know what language you are using but in php it would be:

```
$temp = $_GET['var'];
header("location: http://affiliate.whatever.de/go.cgi?pid=xx&wmid=xxx&cpid=x&prid=xx&target=Suche_Deeplink_Expose&attr1=" . $temp);
```

If you need help with the re-writting of urls I reference my answer to this question: [How to make Clean URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048235/how-to-make-clean-urls)

Ask me any questions if you need more help.