# htaccess pretty urls not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Folder structure:

```
- assets
  - all css / js
- calsses
  - all models, db ant etc
- views
  - admin
  - app
    - index.php
    - customers.php
    .......
```

my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost:8080$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /views/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /views/index.php [L]
```

address : `localhost:8080/app/` - working fine, but then I try to add pretty url for example in my `customers.php` - `localhost:8080/app/customers.php?id=5` change to `localhost:8080/app/customers/id/5`

htaccess added new line:

```
RewriteRule /id/(.*) customers.php?id=$1
```

It's not working, it always return **500 Internal Server Error** there could be the problem?

plus Need all urls without .php extend

Comment: /id/(.*) will always match customers/php?**id**, so your rule will always loop

Comment: so how can I change that line that would work in my case?

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty with that assumption, the issue isn't that line, the issue is your first rule, which will always match and so always add /views/ to the start of your URL. htaccess rules are incredibly easy to mess up. I need to learn a bit more before I try to answer this question well.

Comment: Does that mean you *want* `app` to show in your live site's URLs?

Comment: yes, app I want to show

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to include those conditions for *every rule*. You'd be better off just rewriting everything to, say `views/router.php` then using PHP to include the different controllers, or serve a 404 when the URL isn't valid.

```
RewriteRule !^views/router\.php$ views/router.php [NS,L,DPI]
```

Comment: Yup, also most PHP webapps/frameworks rewrite to an index.php which will load all required code including any routing

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Walf in that handling routes through a router class is a better idea (especially in the long run!) than using `.htaccess` redirects.

However, as your question seems to be more about why is this not working than about how you should do it, here is an explanation for what is going on.

I will be using these URLs as examples:

```
localhost:8080
localhost:8080/app
localhost:8080/app/customers/id/5
```

Your first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost:8080$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /views/$1
```

As you intended, this RewriteRule will match any URL which is not a file, not a directory, and made to localhost:8080.

```
localhost:8080 # not matched because it leads to a directory. 
localhost:8080/app -> localhost:8080/views/app
localhost:8080/app/customers/id/5 -> localhost:8080/views/app/customers/id/5
```

Your next rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /views/index.php [L]
```

It is important to realize that RewriteCond statements apply only to the *first* RewriteRule following them, thus all that is being checked here is the path.

Side note: `^(/)?$`, as you are not using `$1`, can be simplified to `^/?$`.

```
localhost:8080 -> localhost:8080/views/index.php
localhost:8080/views/app # not matched
localhost:8080/views/app/customers/id/5 # not matched
```

As the `L` flag is specified, Apache will immediately stop the current **iteration** and start matching again from the top. [The documentation is badly worded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800150/7186598). Thus, `localhost:8080/views/index.php` will be run through the first rule, fail to match, be run through this rule, fail to match, and then as no other rules exist to check (yet) no rewrite will be done.

Now lets look at what happens when you add your broken rule.

```
RewriteRule /id/(.*) customers.php?id=$1
```

There are a few problems here. First, as you don't require that the URL start with `/id/` the rule will always match a URL that contains `/id/`, even if you have already rewritten the URL. If you amended this by using `^/id/(.*)`, then you would still have issues as the string that the rewrite RegEx is tested against has leading slashes removed. Lastly and most importantly, `customers.php` does not exist in your root directory.

```
localhost:8080/views/index.php # not matched
localhost:8080/views/app # not matched
localhost:8080/views/app/customers/id/5 -> localhost:8080/customers.php?id=5
```

This is the last rule in your file currently, so now Apache will start over. `customers.php` does not exist in your directory, so it will be rewritten to `views/customers.php`. No other rules matched, but the URL has changed and so Apache will start over again, as `/views/customers.php` does not exist, it will be rewritten to `/views/views/customers.php` ... This pattern will repeat until you hit the maximum iteration limit and Apache responds with a 500 error.

You can solve this several ways. Here would be my preferred method, but only if you cannot use a router.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite the main page, even though it is a directory
RewriteRule ^/?$ views/index.php [END]

# Don't rewrite any existing files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .? - [S=999,END]

RewriteRule ^app/?$ views/app/index.php [END]
RewriteRule ^app/id/(.*)$ views/app/customers.php?id=$1 [END]
```

---

**TL;DR** Use a PHP based router. `.htaccess` rules can be incredibly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the question, [How to make Clean URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048235/how-to-make-clean-urls)

I think this is what you needed.

you can use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Having another crack.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?localhost:8080$ [OR]
RewriteCond $0 =views
RewriteRule [^/]* - [END]

RewriteRule ^(app|admin)/([^/]+) views/$1/$2.php [DPI,END]
RewriteRule ^(app|admin)/?$ views/$1/index.php [DPI,END]
```

You may have to use `L` instead of `END` flags if your Apache is older. Set up an ErrorDocument for 404s, too.

Don't muck around with query strings, just parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP, e.g. start by exploding it on `/`. Then you'll have all the parameters of the original pretty URL. You can do that part in an include so each controller can reuse the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your structure and .htaccess file myself and found an endless loop in the apache logs. I bet you got something like this:

```
Mon Nov 28 19:57:32.527765 2016] [core:error] [pid 10] [client 172.18.0.1:35048] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I could fix it by adding the last rule like:

```
RewriteRule id/(.*) /views/app/customers.php?id=$1
```

The leading / is not needed for the match and the target needs the full path. Note that I got the id double (e.g. 123/123) on the url: http://localhost:8080/id/123.

This is caused by one of the 2 previous rules (removing them fixes it) so you might need to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^\/?$ views/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$ views/$1.php?$2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$ views/$1.php [L]
```