# GET request without needing the ? at the end

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get, request

I am developing my login system a bit further to look a lot more professional, and I wanted to know how I could turn get requests into simple links so they look a lot more sleeker?

For example for one of my systems a user can search someones elses profile by going to http://www.example.com/user?user=JimmyJones

Thats all fine and dandy but I don't think it looks very good and many other websites don't have this in their links due to some kind of trick I don't know about, as you can see I have gotten rid of the .php at the end which is done using some very simple htaccess.

But how can I change that link above to:

http://www.example.com/user/JimmyJones

Thank you very much for taking your time to read this and I really hope someone can help me out with my little problem, I assume there is some way to do this in .htaccess?

EDIT:

Here are some websites that do it just about how I would like to do it:

imgur.com/user/example

facebook.com/exampleuser

Comment: you're looking for **url rewriting**. It is usually performed through an apache module, `mod_rewrite`. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @Calimero How would I do this sir, I would be very grateful if you could give me some guidance of what I would write to do this?

Comment: Or you could use a router and the front controller pattern.

Comment: @BigHoss you'll probably find more than you need right here on other questions with the associated tag : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite :-)

Comment: @Progrock I would prefer to use htaccess to do this, but I don't know where I would start or what to write?

Comment: @Calimero I added that tag in, thanks for the feedback there! (I don't know where I would look to find the specific answer I need thought)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Clean URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048235/how-to-make-clean-urls)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess assuming the Apache web server with the rewrite module enabled, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z]+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

The first line says use the rewrite engine.

The second, says match a url that begins (or rather is relative to the .htaccess containing folder) with the pattern 'user' followed by a slash and matching a pattern of any alphabetic characters until the end of the string (not including additional query parameters).

The L flag basically says job done.

If the .htaccess were in the public root:

```
//example.com/user/JimmieJones
```

would map to:

```
//example.com/user.php?user=JimmieJones
```

However it will not match:

```
//example.com/user
//example.com/user/
//example.com/user/JimmieJones/
//example.com/user/Freddy_K9
```

Note that any existing links in your application:

```
<a href="/user?user=JimmieJones">Visit Jimmie's Profile</a>
```

Would likely need to be updated. And with the example pattern above, the old style urls (previously indexed/bookmarked) could fail without your existing rule. You may need to adapt the pattern or set up redirects for the old style.

Managing lots of redirects and rewrites can become a headache.  I'd advice some attention to your url name spacing.  And documenting them.

I reserve first level patterns for aliases/shortcuts/campaigns.

```
//example.com/slug
```

I'd avoid that for your user profile urls if possible.

You'll ideally want to aim for consistency and have one-one correspondence for URLs(with associated http method) and resources (canonical urls).

Comment: Could you please explain this sir? What does the [L] mean and the $1?

Comment: The manual does a better job than I could.  They are called flags. 
 https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

you make `.htaccess` file in the root dictionary then start it with

```
RewriteEngine on
```

then write your rules, For your example it would be like this

```
RewriteRule ^/?user/([^/]+)/?$ user?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

so a full page would be like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?user/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?user=$1
```

just for your example.

Comment: @Progrock Nope, just an example.

Comment: @Progrock That actually the only thing i'm sure about, The optional slashes.