# I have a dynamic URL like http://example.comjobdetail.php?id=24 and I want to change this URL like http://example.comjobdetail/24 how can we do this?

Tags: php, url

I have a dynamic URL like 
http://example.comjobdetail.php?id=24 and 
I want to change this URL like
http://example.comjobdetail/24 
how can we do this ?

Comment: There are many ways, all depending on how your application is structured and run. As it is, your question is way too broad to give you a significative answer.

Comment: This is usually done using a rewrite in the webserver, not in PHP.

Comment: Are you doing this in native PHP (no framework?)? What you are searching is url rewriting (and may require database manipulation, .htaccess). For example https://openclassrooms.com/courses/du-rewriting-realise-avec-du-php
 If you are working on a symfony (or many other framework), thnigs can be way simpler.

Comment: @barmar, what about [slim](https://www.slimframework.com/)?

Comment: What web server are you using? A very common method is using .htaccess and `RewriteRule`s

Comment: @nicolallias a link in French?

Comment: Yeah, I though that was less rude that "let me google that for you" :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Clean URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048235/how-to-make-clean-urls)

Comment: I'm using apache web server and the platform is core PHP and using .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original URL:

http://www.example.com/jobdetail.php?id=24


Desired destination URL:

http://www.example.com/jobdetail/24/


.htaccess syntax:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?jobdetail/([^/d]+)/?$ jobdetail.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

### EDIT

If CSS/ JS don't load, add this line to your jobdetail.php header

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

Comment: sorry the base code must be added in jobdetail.php header!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache web server, you can use .htaccess file for this.
Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^jobdetail\.php$ /jobdetail/%1? [L]
```

Also pls look to the related Question: [.htaccess rewrite "/book.php?id=1234" to "/book/1234"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696718/htaccess-rewrite-book-phpid-1234-to-book-1234)