# Friendly Url for .php?id=1

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have this url

`www.mysite.com/proyecto.php?id=3`

and want this type of url

`www.mysite.com/proyecto/id/3`

I remember using this kind of code but is not working, any idea please?

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule proyecto/id/(.*)/ proyecto.php?id=$1
RewriteRule proyecto/id/(.*) proyecto.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
</ifModule>
```

Finally I improved a bit and I did www.mysite.com/proyecto/1 width the following code in the .htaccess
Thanks for the help!

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule    ^proyecto/([0-9]+)/?$    proyecto.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048235/how-to-make-clean-urls Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: What url are you going to and what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample looks very confusing and does not match your verbal description at all. If I got you right, this is main part you are looking for:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^proyecto/id/(\d+)/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ proyecto/id/%1/? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: @user3430043 was this helpful to you?